# The values DEFAULT and NULL are not allowed in explicit identity columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
insert into A  (id,name,version,date_execution,db_user)
select  NULL id,
       'Suite UC',
       '3.7.08' version,
       GETDATE() heure, 
       name as login
  from sys.server_principals
 where type_desc ='SQL_LOGIN'
   and is_disabled = 0 ;
```

Comment: Show the DDL for your table named "A" (and perhaps use a better name  - don't make your code more difficult to understand). Is column "id" an identity column?

Comment: (I translated your title from French to English. We work in English here.)

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT ... SELECT statement provides a value for your `id` column, and that value is NULL. But `id` is (most likely) declared as an [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186775(v=sql.105)). That means the server generates a new value for it on each INSERT.

Don't try to insert the `id` column, but rather omit it so the server can generate it. This should work:

```sql
insert into A  (name,version,date_execution,db_user)
select 'Suite UC',
       '3.7.08' version,
       GETDATE() heure, 
       name as login
  from sys.server_principals
 where type_desc ='SQL_LOGIN'
   and is_disabled = 0 ;
```